# How to detect the source of exceptions in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

This is a sample case for asking the question in my mind. I have a try block which contains `Convert.ToInt32` and `DateTime.ParseExact` method calls. When catching FormatException, how could I detect the method that throws exception?

Sample code:

```
try
{
    //mStrToDate and mStrToInt are the variables that contains desired time and integer values in string format
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mStrToDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int mIntVar = Convert.ToInt32(mStrToInt);
}
catch (FormatException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);//this line must specify the exception source 
}
```

Comment: Use different try-catch blocks for each function

Comment: Or use `TryParseExact` and `int.TryParse` instead of catching exceptions.

Comment: @BWA This is the easiest way that I thought before. But, what can we do when the code is not simple that much.

Comment: That's what the `TryParse*` methods are for. An exception should be **exceptional**. An invalid input is not exceptional, and throwing exceptions should be avoided.

Comment: i don't understand? the StackTrace already tells you exactly what method the exception occurred in ?

Comment: @GerriePretorius Creating the custom exception classes will resolve the issue. Using **StackTrace detail** I will detect the exception source in this exception which is inherited from FormatException. Then I catch the exceptions with this custom exception classes. Thank you for showing this crucial point that I missed about StackTrace.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do so, if you know that both of your statements can throw the same exception as in your example, **you should use different try-catch blocks** .

```
try
{
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mStrToDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch (FormatException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception from DateTime.Parse" + exc.Message);
}

try
{
    int mIntVar = Convert.ToInt32(mStrToInt);
}
catch (FormatException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception from Convert.ToInt32 " + exc.Message);
}
```

You could write some kind of wrapper that, given a list of calls (actions), will execute the action in a try catch block. That would likey solve (or improve on) the problem of doing all this cleanly on a large number of calls.

---

### Other approaches :

**Dig info from the exception message** :

In some cases, there could be some info in the message itself, but this seems smelly to use a hypothetical part of the string message to classify your result and infer the source.

If identifying the source of the exception is important to you, you should not rely on some message behavior, which might change without notice and break your code.

**Dig info from the exception stack trace** :

The call stack could be used, it seems more reliable to me but much more complicated . But it should work for your case.

**Do not use exceptions**

As mentionned several time in the comments, there is the "tryParse" approach, that is likely to solve your issue in better way. **If the parsings are expected to fail sometimes, then it's not an exception.**

It's part of your normal program flow, and you should treat it as such (with try parse and conditional logic depending on the success of the parsing)

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    //mStrToDate and mStrToInt are the variables that contains desired time and integer values in string format
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mStrToDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int mIntVar = Convert.ToInt32(mStrToInt);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MethodWhereExceptionOccured(ex));//this line must specify the exception source 
}
```

Method to get where error occured

```
    public static string MethodWhereExceptionOccured(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.StackTrace.Split('\r').First().Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

similar to my example , maybe usefull your question

```
try
    {
        //mStrToDate and mStrToInt are the variables that contains desired time and integer values in string format
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(mStrToDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //int mIntVar = Convert.ToInt32(mStrToInt);

        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(line, out mIntVar ))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
            // Whatever
        }

    }
    catch (FormatException exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);//this line must specify the exception source 
    }
```

or you can this simple code

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int mIntVar ;
if (!int.TryParse(line, out mIntVar ))
{
    throw new FormatException();
}
```

Comment: @BobGeiger What is specific to C# 7 here ?

Comment: @BobGeiger . Not c# 7  , I use   C# 5 (.NET Framework v4.5)

Comment: I builded with success, If you have mail adress i I will send you capture @BobGeiger